# How to delete all duplicates in one column and return only those that has date in next column in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with 4+ million rows and 2 columns: 1. phone number (**account**) and last active time (**last_active**).
However, not all accounts has last_active date and have *null* instead. So, what I need is:

**Firstly,** delete all duplicates from account column and return the rest (I need only distinct phone numbers).

**Secondly**, while returning all distinct phone numbers (account), return only those which has a date (not null).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4rkd.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8m57I.png)

Comment: so are you wanting to select this data or actually PURGE/Delete  data?  so you only have 1 account with the most current "Last_Active" date?

Comment: I needed to delete all repeated phone numbers and return the rest, having that last_active is not null. I also illustrated it in picture below. Hope it will explain what I want. Please see my comment below

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be pretty straight forward select query with aggregation.  What have you tried and what error or problem are you getting

```
SELECT Account, max(last_active) as Last_active
FROM TableName
WHERE last_active is not null
GROUP BY Account
```

maybe you don't want the most recent active however...

so maybe: but this would show duplicate accoutns with all "Last_active" dates recorded...

```
SELECT Account, last_active
FROM TableName
WHERE last_active is not null
GROUP BY Account
```

Comment: Hi! I am a new user. Please see my reply above. it was actually directed to you. Your function almost worked but it requires an upgrade. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've just made a sample table in MySQL with about 200,000 records and half of them are duplicates.

The following query works quite well.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE last_active IS NOT NULL
AND 1 GROUP BY account
```

now if you want to save it a new table you could

```
CREATE TABLE newTableName as
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE last_active IS NOT NULL
AND 1 GROUP BY account
```

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with xQbert however I would add in a DISTINCT after the SELECT just in case there are times that account was active twice in the same date (If this is how the column is formatted) and both are recorded

```
SELECT DISTINCT Account, max(last_active) as Last_active
FROM TableName
WHERE last_active is not null
GROUP BY Account
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below simple approach

```
select * from your_table
qualify count(*) over account = 1 
and countif(last_active is null) over account = 0
window account as (partition by account)
```